# Make hover effect stick in an element when mouse is pointed to adjacent element in React Jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to fix my code to maintain the hover effect, if the mouse pointer is in the submenu.
My goal is to make the **red characters and underline stick** when the pointer is inside submenu and to not display if outside menu item and submenu.

**Question:**
How can I force the hover event on the NEW ARRIVALS main menuItem, after my mouse pointer leaves main menuItem and goes to the submenu. How do you do that in JSX? If not, is there anyway to target ::after pseudo element in JSX so that I could just make a conditional to render the style effect?

**I need something to this effect:**

```
if(mouse.is.in.submenu) 
{ 1. I still see main menu item with red characters and the underline
  2. I see the submenu } else {
  Show normal behavior  of onMouseLeave
}
```

[image: MENU]

[image]

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/ecstatic-volhard-shj3j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

**Made the red underline stick by fixing my JSX code as well as my CSS styles.**

Relocated conditional append class is-open to the **li** with the class first-level

```
<li className={`${
  this.state.isOpen && this.state.anchorEl === "arrivals" 
  ? "is-open": "" } first-level`}>
```

**Added and edited CSS styles**

```
.is-open .sub-navigation{
  display: block
}

.is-open .navigation__link, .navigation__link:hover {
  color: #e70033;
}

.is-open .navigation__link:after, .navigation__link:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[CodeSandbox Solution](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/jeromeski/simple-menu-underline-on-hover-effect/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**note:**
*Based on my research here in stackoverflow you cannot directly target pseudo:: elements in React using JSX * which answers my original question if I can somehow control :hover in JSX.